# Is there an additional resistance given by a specific "protection" than a general one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I add Protection 4 to an armour piece,will it reduce the same amount of damage as an armour piece with a "specific" protection such as Fire Protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, I'm pretty sure that fire resistance protects against only fire, but protects more. protection 4 (which, I must add, I admire you for getting) protects against almost everything but protects less.

Comment: I think I just got to Protection 3 on survival(I planned to get another Protection 3 book to combine. I was just asking before getting it. @user118394